# Alignment issue with twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For the first time I'm using a bootstrap-based template for my website.
It has several advantages but makes it very difficult for me to align the elements the way I want.

What I would like is to place the "carousel text" between the "John Smith" text and the address (avenue de la gare...). Current the carousel text keeps sticking above john smith which is not what I want.

They are so many files in the template that I haven't been able to reproduce the issue on JSFiddle, therefore here is a link to download the files https://tu1.s3.amazonaws.com/880A71692498/cssissue.zip

You can also see the issue in live [here](http://goo.gl/8pG9HX)

Many thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for ".carousel-inner" class add  "top:76px" and adjust avenue text little bit with margin

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Do you think there's a cleaner way to do this? Looking at the John Smith and address text, it seems that the carousel has an impact on them (these texts get slightly blurred each time the carousel changes to the next item). Many thanks

Comment: actually the problem with placing the containers, the carousel text is another container and John smith is in different container, if you can slider in the same container as john smith, by using floats you can position the container.